# How to implement Fastlane Match into an existing enterprise project

Tags: jenkins, fastlane, fastlane-match

Self explanatory, but a few points:

Our enterprise app solution is already using Fastlane using sigh and cert commands with the certs stored locally on a Jenkins node. We want to migrate to using Match, however I am having a hard time finding good examples of how to accomplish this in an existing project and to be honest it seems a little 'automagical' as I am not a Devops person. We are using Match, Jenkins and AWS S3 & Parameter Store for the certs and creds.

Some curiosities:

- Are there any good examples of Match being used with this setup?
- How does the Matchfile pull environment variables from a Jenkins pipeline script?
- Is Match essentially a replacement for cert storage?
- Does the match function in a lane replace sigh and cert functions?

Before someone says, "ShOw YoUr FaStFiLe"; I'm not able to share any code. This is more a question to obtain good resources for implementation of match and to gain a better understanding.

Thanks